# detect CNAME in DNS answer

Tags: c, dns, network-programming

I am trying to create a client that will parse a DNS reply.

What is the right place to check for a record type of CNAME? It seems like when I do a wireshark capture of www.google.com DNS lookup, the reply does a lookup on picasa.google.com which has a CNAME record come back that has a picasa.l.google.com name, so that is messing up my code that is parsing the A record types.

is there any example code that talks about how to parse CNAME and A records in the same reply?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want an example you can go to:

http://www.binarytides.com/dns-query-code-in-c-with-linux-sockets/

In this code you can set first the type of query (qinfo->qtype)...

And after parse yourself the response ;)

Good luck...

Comment: It looks like this guy is only parsing things that are type 1, not CNAME, MX, etc

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for an open source implementation, i have used and extended Domain name relay demon [dnrd](http://dnrd.sourceforge.net/)

with the precise parsing code in file 
[dns.c](http://dnrd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dnrd/trunk/dnrd/src/dns.c?revision=250&view=markup)

look for the api snprintf_cname